# Восстановление базы данных MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

Когда я делаю восстановление, выдаёт ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Версия Mssql=> Standart Edition(x64). 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему

Comment: Снять секционирование. Как крайний случай - перекачать  данные таблицы через "Связанные серверы".

Comment: Связаные серверы позволяют перебрасывать информацию между двумя mssql серверами как туда так и назад типа insert into table1 select * from [server_ip].[dbBase].[dbo].[table1]. Почитать тут google "mssql связанные серверы" => https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff772782%28v=sql.120%29.aspx .  От себя скажу что позний с ранним сервером связываются но не наоборот (я связал 2014ЕЕ с 2005). На вкладке безопасность указать последняя 4 галочка логин пароль базы.Так же можно привязывать другие СУБД, но другие не советую.

Comment: проще уж поставить триал Enterprise и поднять бэкап на нем. он 180 дней работает без активации, более чем достаточно для того, чтобы восставновить бэкап и отключить в нем секционирование

Comment: @PashaPash просто у меня готовый бэкап, изменить нельзя

Comment: @propro17 поставить триал, поднять на него бэкап, отключить секионирование (если секционирование для индекса - пересоздать его, если для таблицы - [перелить данные в несекицонированную](http://www.patrickkeisler.com/2013/01/how-to-remove-undo-table-partitioning.html). После опять забэкапить.

Comment: @PashaPash у меня секционирование для таблицы. Прочитал то, что отправили не понял как делается(

Comment: @propro17 создается новая таблица без секционирования, в основной файловой группе. в нее перегоняются данные из старой. потом старая таблица удаляется. новая переименовывается.

Comment: @PashaPash `PartitionTable2` , где вы  отправили мне, это и есть вторая таблица да?

Comment: @PashaPash  у меня секционирование для индекса будет, как мне его пересоздать, если есть зависимости

Comment: удалить внешние ключи, пересоздать таблицу, вернуть внешние ключи